# Makefile: python: command not found

Tags: python, python3, makefile

I have a Makefile that contains these two lines

```
run: sim
    @python run.py $(INPUT)
```

When I tried to run `make run`, I got the error message saying `python` is not found. I soon realized that was because I had only `python3`, so I added the line

```
alias python=python3
```

to the file `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` separately. That is, I tried to fix the problem twice by adding this alias to two different files. However, even after I sourced the file and could run `python` in the terminal, `make run` still gave the same error.

However, the problem is fixed after I install a package by running `apt install python-is-python3`. Although I don't have this problem anymore, I do not know how it was fixed. Isn't `python-is-python3` just creating a symlink from `/usr/bin/python` to `python3`? Is it any different from the alias approach I tried?

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't python-is-python3 just creating a symlink from /usr/bin/python to python3?

Yes it is.

> Is it any different from the alias approach I tried?

Yes it is - bash aliases are only expanded in an *interactive bash shell*. The shell used by `make` is `/bin/sh` by default, and is not interactive. Symbolic links are handled at the filesystem level and are hence independent of the shell.

For further discussion about shells and Makefiles, see [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/4440445)

Comment: But I remember `~/.profile` would be used for non-interactive shells as well. Actually it is specify [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). Does it mean the shell used by Makfile does not come with `--login` option?

Comment: `~/.profile` would be read by a `/bin/sh` *login* shell; but even if `make` executed commands in a login shell (it doesn't, AFAIK), the fact that it would do so non-interactively would disable aliases.